# Colocar iconos en un proyecto de laravel que esta en cPanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, cpanel, font-awesome

lo que sucede es que tengo un proyecto montado en el servidor de cpanel pero a la hora de verlo todo aparece bien excepto los iconos, cosa que en local no pasa.

Me preguntaba si me podían ayudar con ese problema

Donde se supone que debería estar el icono aparece un cuadro trasparente

Asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando font awesome

Error en la consola [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo subí el proyecto de la siguiente forma:

-Comprimí todo el proyecto en zip menos la carpeta public, la carpeta public la comprimí por aparte entonces quede con 2 zip, un zip del proyecto y otro con solo la carpeta public

-Fui al cpanel y en el mismo directorio de publichtm(no dentro de publichtml) cree una carpeta con el nombre del proyecto y descomprimí el zip del proyecto ahi

-luego en publichtml descomprimí el zip de public y en el index.php acomode las rutas del vendor y el bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes mirar si subiste la carpeta de font awesome , si es asi y no la encuentra mira la consola de chrome ahi aparecera si no estas aputando bien al archivo, a lo mejor no has definido una url absoluta y por eso en ambiente local si la encuetra pero al subir a un host compartido no la va encontrar, te recomiendo subir un pantallazo de tu consola al cargar la pagina

Comment: efectivamente había error en la consola pero estaba oculto, ahí subí la captura

Comment: si lo solucionaste sube como lo hiciste en la respuesta

Comment: no lo he podido solucionar bro

Comment: el problema esta con la ruta en donde ubicaste la libreria, asegurate de haber declarado una url absoluta y que esta este apuntando correctamente, recuerda que muchas veces por seguridad movemos archivos y solo dejamos la vista en publichtml del host

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. Yo subi mi proyecto con la carpeta normal en el directorio donde esta publichtml y en public html puse la carpeta llamada app y contiene los archivos public y en index.html de esa carpeta app cambio los enlaces de bootstrap y vendor o algo asi pero no se si es porque lo monte así o que

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y subir un pantallaso de como subiste los archivos a cpanel, toma una captura todo el arbol de directorio para entender como has subido los archivos

Comment: Listo amigo, ya actualicé la pregunta

Comment: por como veo deberias tener en publichtml una carpeta fonts y dentro de esta tiene vendor, cosa que veo ilogica, tienes dos opciones, mover el vendor a como te dije primeramente o modificar el src de donde carga los iconos, puedes hacer lo mismo, ../ para que retore y ahi si buscas tu archivo